# can't add a card to Apple Wallet to use with Apple Pay

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, flutter, in-app-purchase

can't add a card to Apple Wallet to use with Apple Pay[Screen_shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYyx1.jpg)